# ObjectDump android's libutil.so and I found there are the same offset addresses for different functions' symbols

Tags: android

I performed the command as below:
objectdump -TC libutils.so
libutils.so is compiled out by android source code.

I found the following result:

```
000129a1  w   DF .text  0000000a android::Vector<android::sp<android::WorkQueue::WorkThread> >::do_move_backward(void*, void const*, unsigned int) const
000129a1  w   DF .text  0000000a android::Vector<android::sp<android::WorkQueue::WorkThread> >::do_move_forward(void*, void const*, unsigned int) const
```

The two function do_move_backward and do_move_forward  have the same offset address.
The problem is that how are they mapped to memory without mistake? Is correct function will be founded when program is running?

Answer (score 0):

I found the phenomenon happens always for template.
It happens when  the functions have the same template parameters and the same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
0000dcbb  w   DF .text  00000002 android::Vector<android::sysprop_change_callback_info>::do_construct(void*, unsigned int) const
0000dcbb  w   DF .text  00000002 android::Vector<android::sysprop_change_callback_info>::do_destroy(void*, unsigned int) const
```

The template parameters are same. But function names are not same.